# ParseError: syntax error, unexpected identifier &quot;file_put_contents&quot;

Tags: php, laravel, post

I am trying to do small example on POST . Here's my controller

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
public function createProduct(Request $request){
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $description = $request->input('description');
    $price=$request->input('price');
    $brand=$request->input('brand');
    
    if(!$name || !$description || !$price || !$brand){
        return response()->json([
            'message'=>'Invalid payload ','data'=>null
        ],400);
    }
    
    $filePath='C:\xampp\htdocs\firstWebsite\resources\products_list.json';
    $fileContent=file_get_contents($filePath);  
    $jsonContent=json_decode($fileContent,true);
    
    $payload=[
        'name'=>$name,
        'description'=>$description,
        'price'=>$price,
        'brand'=>$brand
    ];
    
    if(!$jsonContent || !is_array($jsonContent){
        $content=[
            $payload
        ]
        
        file_put_contents($filePath, json_encode($content));
    }
    else{
        $jsonContent[]=$payload;
        file_put_contents($filePath, json_encode($jsonContent));
    }
    
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Product Added','data'=>$payload
    ]);         
}
```

and I'm using postman to test it , I've put the right url and I've chosen body and raw options then json , and I've written a small json file which is

```
{
"name":"Product1",
"brand":"Brand1",
"price":20.99,
"description":"Product 1 "
}
```

when I click send it shows this error .
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected identifier  "file_put_contents"C:\xampp\htdocs\firstWebsite\app\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php on line 37

Any ideas how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon at the end of this line :

```
    $content=[
        $payload
    ];
```

Comment: I've put it earlier that's why I removed it  because new error happens at that line  when I put it it says .                                               
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected token &quot;;&quot; in file C:\xampp\htdocs\firstWebsite\app\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php on line 35